# Magento 2 Admin Custom Form Fields Creation

Tags: magento2, grid

I am creating Custom Grid in Magento 2 admin. I need when we click any button it should show div with form fields in Magento 2 Admin. Please find the screen shot.

Screen Shot :
[image]